# Error using openOrCreateDatabase in android (Could not open database)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database from within a class. The app stops working on run on Api 22+ and I get this error in logcat:

```
Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

The code:

```
public class G extends Application {

public static SQLiteDatabase database;
public static final String   DIR_SDCARD   = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String   DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/DO_NOT_DELETE/";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    new File(DIR_DATABASE).mkdirs();
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "/database.sqlite", null);

   }
}
```

I have no problem running it on Android versions that are lower than 5. I also added the required permission in AndroidManifest.xml. What could be the problem?

Comment: For **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** you need Runtime External sorage permission from Android 6.0

Comment: @Muthukrishnan Rajendran I tried to run the app on Android 5.1.1 but it still stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I made a dumb mistake. I tried to create/open a database on an emulator that didn't have a sdcard storage. Now I gave it some space for sdcard and it's working fine.